# Javascript - displaying locale time from mySQL TimeDate

Tags: javascript, php, date, timezone, momentjs

I am having an issue with displaying the correct time.  I have a php script that when a button is clicked it inserts the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP into the database. The server is located in Arizona, I am in PST. When I call the time in my script it shows Arizona time, but I need it to show the users time.  So 2015-02-18 16:06:28 Arizona time, MY time is 2015-02-18 15:06:28.

How do i get the correct time. I am using moment.js, but no matter how i format it it shows the incorrect time. I am not sure but is DST, not being considered?

```
var time_in = time_in;//format 2015-02-18 16:17:33
var timeIn = moment.utc(time_in, "HH:mm a").format("HH:mm a");
```

Comment: Is PHP or Javascript getting the time? Because PHP is server-side and Javascript is client-side.

Comment: php is setting the time using now();

Comment: So if my "timestamp" is 2015-02-18 15:00:00, and I am in PST I want to show 14:00 or 3:00 PM. If i am in EST want to show 18:00.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. I thought this was about putting the right date in the database using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Moment.js` parses the date as a locale date-time. So when you do `moment.utc(time_in)`, you're converting it to UTC according to your local time (PST), shifted forward or backwards.

So what you need to do is do a [moment.fn.utcOffset](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/). Arizona is UTC-07:00, so we would want to add +7 to the offset. You can do the same using [moment.fn.zone](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/timezone-offset/) but that's getting deprecated.

```
var utcTime = moment.utc('2015-02-18 16:06:28').utcOffset(+7).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
// returns "2015-02-18 23:06:28" which is the UTC time
```

Now you have the moment in UTC, you can convert it to the client localtime:

```
moment(moment.utc(utcTime).toDate()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
// returns '2015-02-18 15:06:28' (which is PST)
```

`moment.utc(utcTime).toDate()` above just converts the utc time to your local time, then formatting it with `momentjs`

EDIT: If possible, you should use [unix timestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) when sending to server, then you don't have to deal with UTC or timezones. You can convert to local time with `moment.unix(unixTimestamp).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')`

Comment: Thank you trekforever. This is getting the  results i wanted.  I was not thinking about the utcOffset(+7).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Javascript to get the time of the client, but then not passing that to the PHP. I'm not sure how your app is structured, but you could create an `input` tag with the `type="hidden"`. Then using Javascript, find the element and set it's `value` to `Date()`.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/43jfefuq/

Now when you submit this form with PHP, the value in the field will be the client's local time.